# How to determine the value format is dd-mmm-yyyy in xslt

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to determine the input value having date format of dd-mmm-yyyy. If I can find will set some attribute based on the attribute I can do the format in C# report processing class.

```
    <td>
 <xsl:if test="To write expression to match the value">
        <r>
        <xyz:value-of select="'Set Value'" />
        </r>
</xsl:if>
</td>
```

Input value is "30-Jun-2019". If it matches I want to set .
Basically I have set of columns in the report. I have to identify the the values in the report if the value matches with the Date format of dd-mmm-yyy setting some attribute in the xslt and applying the same format in report parser code which is written in c#

Comment: Please show a sample of your input and desired output. If you can move forwards to XSLT 2.0/3.0 it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Input value is "30-Jun-2019". If it matches I want to set <xyz:value-of select="'DateFormateToBeCorrected'" />.
Basically I have set of columns in the report. I have to identify the the values in the report if the value matches with the Date format of dd-mmm-yyy setting some attribute in the xslt and applying the same format in report parser code which is written in c#

Comment: There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0, so your tags make no sense. Anyway, your question i9s still not clear.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if the input value is in a DD-MMM-YYYY format?

Comment: michael.hor257k - Yes. I want to know how to determine the input value is in DD-MMM-YYYY format.

Comment: Do you also want to check the date is valid? i.e "31-Feb-2019" is in DD-MMM-YYYY format, but is not actually a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, there is no regex support in XSLT 1.0, so this can get quite tedious.

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>21-Jan-1987</item>
    <item>921-Jan-1987</item>
    <item>15-Jul-2009</item>   
    <item>15-Jux-2009</item>   
    <item>03-Dec-2014</item>
    <item>03-Dec-999</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <item value="{.}">
                <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring-before(., '-')" />
                <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="substring-before(substring-after(., '-'), '-')" />
                <xsl:variable name="yyyy" select="substring-after(substring-after(., '-'), '-')" />
                <xsl:if test="translate($dd, '123456789', '000000000') = '00' and translate($yyyy, '123456789', '000000000') = '0000' and ($mmm='Jan' or $mmm='Feb' or $mmm='Mar' or $mmm='Apr' or $mmm='May' or $mmm='Jun' or $mmm='Jul' or $mmm='Aug' or $mmm='Sep' or $mmm='Oct' or $mmm='Nov' or $mmm='Dec')">
                    <xsl:text>Is Date</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <item value="21-Jan-1987">Is Date</item>
  <item value="921-Jan-1987"/>
  <item value="15-Jul-2009">Is Date</item>
  <item value="15-Jux-2009"/>
  <item value="03-Dec-2014">Is Date</item>
  <item value="03-Dec-999"/>
</output>
```

Note that this checks only that the input conforms to the pattern, not that the date itself is valid. Also keep in mind that XML is case-sensititve.

---

**Added:**

If you prefer, you could simplify the test to:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(translate(translate(., '123456789', '000000000'), 'JFMASOND', '@@@@@@@@'), 'anebpryulgctov', '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%') = '00-@%%-0000'">
```

but then a value like `15-Jpt-2009` will pass as date.

Comment: This approach works for me. I have used contains option to match with lower and upper case months. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 this is fairly trivial: `matches(., '[0-9]{2}-[A-Z][a-z]{2}-[0-9]
{4}')`

In 1.0 it's considerably harder, and it depends a little bit how precise you want to be. But you could get close with `translate(translate($input, 'ABC...abc...', 'AAAAAAAA....'), '0123456789', '9999999999') = '99-AAA-9999')` where the '...' means you have to write out the rest of the alphabet.

Comment: In this where i have to pass the input value? - translate(translate('ABC...abc...', 'AAAAAAAA....', ''), '0123456789', '9999999999') = '99-AAA-9999')

Comment: I've edited the answer to use` $input` as the input value.